# How to create an object from a different class in java

Tags: java

I am pretty new to java, and was wondering how to create an object of a different class. I would extend that class, however I am already extending another. For example:

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    //How do I create a "Chupacabra" object in here?
    Chupacabra jeff = new Chupacabra();
    //I've been doing this^, but it says "Cannot be resolved as type"
}

public class Chupacabra {

}
```

Or am I crazy? I know it doesn't make much sense to make a Chupacabra object in there, but... I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to merely have an instance of `Chupacabra` class inside of the `Dog` class, then you can declare it as an instance variable, as such:

**Dog.java**:

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
    Chupacabra myChupacabra = new Chupacabra();

    //...
}
```

**Chupacabra.java**:

```
public class Chupacabra {

}
```

Note that the `Dog` class needs to be declared in `Dog.java` and that the `Chupacabra` class needs to be declared in `Chupacabra.java`.

For more information on declaring member variables in Java, please see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

Comment: That's what I've been doing, except it says that it "cannot be resolved to a type". Am I supposed to import something?

Comment: Are you certain that the two classes are in different files?

Comment: They are in different files. And different packages.

Comment: @user3750325 If they are in different packages, you will need to add an `import` statement in `Dog.java`.  Which package is the `Chupacabra` class in?

Comment: So if the Chupacabra class is in package "packageName", I would have to say "import packageName.Chupacabra" at the top of Dog?

Comment: @user3750325 Exactly.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Dog extends Animal{        
    Chupacabra ch = new Chupacabra(); //creating "Chupacabra" object
}

class Chupacabra {

}
```

You can't have two public classes under one .java name; so I removed 'public' from the second class.

If you want, you can keep the second class as "Chupacabra.java"

Comment: That's what I've been doing, except it says that it "cannot be resolved to a type". Am I supposed to import something?

Comment: Are you using these classes inside any package?

Comment: Could you update your code with complete package information?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, and assuming `Chupacabra` is in the same package as `Dog`. You could use the default constructor like -

```
public class Dog extends Animal{
  //How do I create a "Chupacabra" object in here?
  private Chupacabra myChupacabra = new Chupacabra();
}
```

If `Chupacabra` is in a different package from `Dog` then you will need to import `Chupacabra`.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, except it says that it "cannot be resolved to a type". Am I supposed to import something?

Comment: @user3750325 Edited. If `Chupacabra` isn't in the same package as `Dog` then you will need to import `Chupacabra`.

Comment: Ok, it's in a different package. At the top of the Dog file, would I do: import packagename.Chupacabra?

Comment: @user3750325 After `package dogpackage;`, and assuming `Chupacabra` is in `packagename`.